# npm package uses fs in wrong dir

Tags: node.js, npm, fs

I have made a very simple [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kifo) to support my discord bot.

In my bot code, I am trying to use a function from my package. However, when I launch bot code, I receive this error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'prefixes.json'`

I have a `prefixes.json` file in the main dir **of npm package**. In the package this code (which returns an error) is executed:

```
const contents = fs.readFileSync(`prefixes.json`);
const jsonPrefixes = JSON.parse(contents);
```

This code is executed when I turn on my discord bot that is dependant on this package. `prefix.json` is in the same dir as `index.js` of my npm package. I tried `./prefix.json` and `prefix.json`, none of which worked.

Is the error because the package tries to search in my bot dir, instead of his own? How do I overcome this?

Update: When I tried `./node_modules/kifo/prefixes.json` it worked, but I don't want it like that - is there a way to provide a path relative to the package?

Comment: Be careful providing such a path. Might not work if somebody uses `npx` without `npm install` as your module is then in a temp folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `require()` instead of `fs.readFileSync()`:

```
const jsonPrefixes = require('./prefixes.json');
const contents = JSON.stringify(jsonPrefixes); // you don't actually need this
```

#### Why?

The reason why `fs.readFileSync()` must behave the way it does is because file API in all programming languages behave that way. Say for example you write a program called `dump`. The working directory **must** be the one the user is currently in otherwise if you do:

```
> cd /my/folder
> ls
test.txt
> dump test.txt
Error: cannot open /path/to/node_modules/dump/test.txt
```

Of course YOU DO NOT EXPECT THIS. Nor should you. **You should not expect fs.readFileSync to use it's own module directory to open files from**.

On the other hand, `require()` was designed to load javascript modules, some of which are form your own project. So `require()` will open files from the directory the code is in.

The `require()` function can load either javascript code or a JSON file. So in your case you can use `require()`.

#### What if it's not JSON?

If you cannot use `require()` you can use the `__dirname` variable. It is a special variable that contains the path of the currently executing module:

```
const contents = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/prefixes.json`);
const jsonPrefixes = JSON.parse(contents);
```

However for JSON I still prefer to use `require()`.